# BASH - Find files older dan MODIFICATION / CREATION date

Tags: linux, bash, samba

I’m struggeling with the following: I have a samba share where people can put stuff into. I would like it to check for files and folders older than 30 days and delete these. Keep in mind that a file might been MADE back in 2001 but it needs to start counting from them moment I put in that folder. Other problem: what if the folder is > 30 days but someone put newer files in the folder? The folder shouldn’t then be deleted.

What I’ve found so far:

`find /mnt/map/ -ctime -30`

But I don’t know if this is correct and what I need?

Comment: File birth date is a complex question because it is available on some OSes/filesystems but not on others. Moreover, if it is available, there is no guarantee that it has not been inherited from a copy/move operation or even modified with a dedicated command. Anyway, several pieces of information would help: in your case, as it is a Samba share, you have 3 players: the server (what OS?, what filesystem?), the client (GNU/Linux? what filesystem?), and the Samba protocol (what version?). Depending on these the answers may vary.

Comment: You cannot rely on the access/creation/modification times, you'll have to keep record of what's happening on the share yourself. On a Linux Samba server I would go with `tmpfiles.d` that almost does what you want; for example, removing files/dirs that weren't _accessed_ for 30 days

Comment: @ironman The `ctime` is not the creation time, it is the change time. It is updated when the content of the file and/or the attributes change. And the `find` command from the GNU findutils has no option corresponding to a creation time. You can do some tests: `stat` one of your files (`stat filename`), if the output shows `Birth: -` you probably don't have this creation time information on your share (not 100% sure). Else it is there but the options of `find` from GNU findutils will not give you access to it.

Comment: When you are ok with the `-c` or `-m` option in find, you can consider `find /mnt/map/ -ctime -30 -type f -delete` and next delete empty dirs `find /mnt/map/ -type d -empty -delete`, but this approach would also delete recent empty directories.